# backbone collection won't empty on reset

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I have a calendar day model, and in each calendar day, I have a collection of events.

If the day has events, the collection is refreshed, no problem, I show the new events. However, if the day has no events, the collection isn't being emptied, and the collection still shows the events from the day which was the last model (previous day if the user went to next day).

I've got the collection being created in the fetch success of the model, so it shouldn't be an async issue.

My model is

```
Myapp.Models.CalDay = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url:'calendar',
    initialize: function(){

        this.get_cal();
        },
    get_cal: function(){

        //calendar doesn't exist, so first time through,
            Myapp.CurrentCal = this;
            Myapp.cal.set({'date': new Date(),'draw_slider': true,'put_date':'today'});
            Myapp.CurrentCal.Events = new Myapp.Collections.DayEvents();
            this.bind('change:date',this.fetch_cal);
            this.fetch_cal();
        } 

        Myapp.CurrentCal.bind("fetched",this.get_view);
    },

    fetch_cal: function(){

        console.log(Myapp.CurrentCal.Events);

        Myapp.Calendar.fetch({
        success: function(response) {

            Myapp.CurrentCal.Events.reset(response.attributes.calendar_events);
            Myapp.CurrentCal.trigger("fetched");
                },
          error: function() {
              alert('error getting calendar');
            }
        });


    },
    get_view: function(){
          console.log(Myapp.CurrentCal.Events);
          new Myapp.Views.CalendarDay();

    }
});
```

Comment: Are you calling `remove()` on the view when a new day is accessed?

Comment: Ok, went ahead and answered with what I think the issue likely is. If I'm wrong, will you post your _view_ and _controller_ definitions too?

Comment: sorry @rudolph9  I wasn't expecting an answer that quickly. I've responded below to your answer.

Comment: if the day has no events what does `response.attributes.calendar_events` return ? And does it go in success callback ?

Comment: @Cyclone the callback does not return a calendar_events array when there are no events. I does trigger the response success. I was checking for `response.attributes.calendar_events.length`, and then reset, but it was alway returning as having the length of the old calendar day when there were events. So, same issue. Checking for `response.attributes.calendar_events.length>0` or `response.attributes.calendar_events`is always triggered if it has a calendar_events or not.

Comment: One more question, might be silly, but how does your server know that which day is asked for? When events are not present, considering that server sends the same old response, there might be something wrong on the server code also.

Comment: @Cyclone, the date is sent in the request to the server. That side is working fine as I can ping the api for the output and see what is being returned. I can also see on the server that the correct page is being requested, so server side looks good.

Comment: @Cyclone, turns out you were somewhat correct. The server wasn't returning any `calendar_events` so I thought Backbone would remove the collection in the reset, as there is nothing to set. Even calling `reset` with nothing in the reset should remove everything from the collection I would have thought. It doesn't. The answer is you have to return an empty array and pass that to the collection reset, so you are correct that the issue was on the server, as I couldn't test for an empty array within javascript because backbone would just use the old array. If you submit your answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @pedalpete, thanks !! I have posted answer, have kept it small and generic :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-reset) says calling `reset` without passing any models as argument will empty `collection`. So for all the `days` where there are no `events` you need to call `reset` without passing models as an argument or return empty array from the server as you said.

And / Or you can make a check for response in the `success` callback and based on the conditions call either

```
Myapp.CurrentCal.Events.reset(response.attributes.calendar_events);
```

or

```
Myapp.CurrentCal.Events.reset();
```

Comment: just a note, I was calling an empty reset but that wasn't working. the solution for me was returning an empty array.

Comment: ohh ok, I assumed it would work as its said in the documentation, will verify though, thanks :)

Comment: The documentation does *not* say what you claim it does, or maybe it changed.  You state "calling reset without *any* arguments will empty collection", the documentation states (and I quote it *exactly*): "Calling collection.reset() without passing *any models as arguments* will empty the entire collection" -- reset take arguments *besides* models

Comment: Yes, George, my bad. The words you said explain it better than what I had written, I just updated the answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `remove()` your view before (well, I'd sugest before) rendering the next days events.

This in the case where you render a new days *with* events this is not causing you issues because the container of the view is being over written with these events. However, in the case where the next day contains *zero* new events, nothing is written and hence you are left with the previous days events still being displayed.

Consider creating a close method for your view and along with executing the `remove()` function on the view also clean up any binding you have associated with that view.

I have been creating a `config/backone.coffee` for my backbone apps and creating a `close()` function to accomplish this:

```
class Backbone.View extends Backbone.View
  close: ->
    @beforeClose() if @beforeClose?
    @remove()
    @unbind(null,null,this)
```

Comment: I have `$(this.el).clear()`, but that isn't solving the problem. If I call 'remove', I actually remove the spot in the dom where the calendar events are added in, and I don't want to do that, right? I was under the impression that the strength of backbone.js was that the data was not bound by the DOM. The problem isn't only what is being shown, as I am re-drawing the events when I change the day. The problem is that the events from another day are being redrawn. You could be correct, but I thought your logic is going against the benefit of backbone.

Comment: @pedalpete Modularize you program more, create a view inside a view where the calendar it self is a view and then being rendering within it is a view for each day and with in that a view for each event.  You can find a decent example [here](https://github.com/ccoenraets/backbone-cellar/blob/master/tutorial/final/js/views/winelist.js) where a view is rendered for the winelist it self and within it a view for each wine in the list is also be rendered.

Comment: The events are already modularized like that, but I only show one day at a time. But I'm doing some restructuring and seeing if "remove" solves the issue.